# Creating a dataframe using roll-forward window on multivariate time series

Tags: time-series, pandas, sampling, multivariate-distribution

Based on the simplifed sample dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
timestamps = pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01', end='2017-01-5', inclusive='left')
values = np.arange(0,len(timestamps))
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': values ,'B' : values*2},
                       index = timestamps )
print(df)

            A  B
2017-01-01  0  0
2017-01-02  1  2
2017-01-03  2  4
2017-01-04  3  6
```

I want to use a roll-forward window of size 2 with a stride of 1 to create a resulting dataframe like

```
     timestep_1  timestep_2  target  
0  A 0           1           2         
   B 0           2           4         
1  A 1           2           3
   B 2           4           6
```

I.e., each window step should create a data item with the two values of A and B in this window and the A and B values immediately to the right of the window as target values.

My first idea was to use pandas

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

But that seems to only work in combination with aggregate functions such as *sum*, which is a different use case.

Any ideas on how to implement this rolling-window-based sampling approach?

Answer (score 1):

You might solve it using Pandas Shift operation.

```
Original df:
            Col1  Col2  Col3
2020-01-01    10    13    17
2020-01-02    20    23    27
2020-01-03    15    18    22
2020-01-04    30    33    37
2020-01-05    45    48    52
```

Time Lapsing Code:

```
df.Col1.shift(periods=1)
df.Col2.shift(periods=2)
df.Col3.shift(periods=3)
```

Now:

```
             Col1  Col2  Col3
2020-01-01    NaN   NaN   NaN
2020-01-02    20    NaN   NaN
2020-01-03    15    18    NaN
2020-01-04    30    33    37
2020-01-05    45    48    52
```

More details can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

Note: Shift supports negative movement also.

Comment: "Shift" may be part of the solution, but your resulting dataframe is not exactly what I was looking for.